# Convert string to List<string> in one line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics, string

I have a string:

```
var names = "Brian,Joe,Chris";
```

Is there a way to convert this to a `List<string>` delimited by `,` in one line?

Comment: I don't understand the "in one line" requirement.  Shoot for writing code that is clear and understandable, not ways to fit an operation into as small a space as possible.

Comment: With the advent of LINQ, "one liners" that are readable and clean have become much more common in C# IMO.

Comment: @Ed S. - While I agree that "in one line" may not be the best way to put it, single-line statements like the one Matt Greer provides tend to be very clear and understandable. My guess is he just wants to avoid using a `for` loop, which is more tedious, error prone, and unclear.

Comment: I don't mean to say that one-liners are inherently harder to understand, I am just saying that it shouldn't ever be a requirement.  Just do it the best way available.  If that happens to be in one line, great, but it's not something that should shape the way you write your code.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

```
List<string> result = names.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
```

Or even cleaner by Dan's suggestion:

```
List<string> result = names.Split(',').ToList();
```

Comment: You may have put it there on purpose, but I always leave out the whole `new char[] { }` part. It's more readable that way, to *me* at least.

Comment: @Dan: I agree, and generally I do use the params overload. But for an answer to a question sometimes I feel like verbosity is better. Just a matter of opinion really.

Comment: ToList() doesn't seem to be avail anymore?

Comment: Did you bring in the `System.LINQ` namespace?

Answer (score 53):

The `List<T>` has a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```cs
List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>(names.Split(','));
```

Comment: Excellent - no need to import System.Linq

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this because it prevents a single item list with an empty item if your source string is empty:

```
  IEnumerable<string> namesList = 
      !string.isNullOrEmpty(names) ? names.Split(',') : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Split a string delimited by characters and return all non-empty elements.

```
var names = ",Brian,Joe,Chris,,,";
var charSeparator = ",";
var result = names.Split(charSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a list and want to add values from a delimited string, you can use [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`InsertRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
existingList.AddRange(names.Split(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string given="Welcome To Programming";
List<string> listItem= given.Split(' ').ToList();//Split according to space in the string and added into the list
```

output:

```
Welcome

To 

Programming
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stringify.Library nuget package

```
//Default delimiter is ,
var split = new StringConverter().ConvertTo<List<string>>(names);

//You can also have your custom delimiter for e.g. ;
var split = new StringConverter().ConvertTo<List<string>>(names, new ConverterOptions { Delimiter = ';' });
```