# converting string to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

What I am trying to do is convert a string to a List of strings using linq.  I try the following line of code:

```
value = "one,two,three,four";

List<string> arr = value.Split(',').Select(s => s.ToList());
```

But I am getting the error:

**Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

If anyone could provide some help that would be awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011467/convert-string-to-liststring-in-one-line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hello you can try with

```
 value.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got the `ToList` on each individual array element - i.e. on each string. That call itself is valid because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, but it means you're creating an `IEnumerable<List<char>>` which isn't what you want.

I don't think you need the `Select` at all - just use:

```
List<string> arr = value.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the list constructors [takes an enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0):

```
var arr = new List<string>(value.Split(','));
```

Not sure why people insist on linq extensions for *everything*...

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, but I find the LINQ version more readable (no angle brackets, no nested regular brackets).

Comment: @jeroenh Undoubtedly, and likely the extension method implementation uses this constructor anyway. I just find it funny how many things are styled like linq extensions these days :-) I'd use either without a second thought, which for me is most important as spending a second thought on it is a little bit of a waste.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = "one,two,three,four";

List<string> arr = value.Split(',').Select(s => s).ToList();
```

or simpler:

```
List<string> arr = value.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't need select, but still if you want to use it then it should be:

```
  List<string> arr = value.Split(',').Select(s => s).ToList();
```

Or you can simply do :

```
  List<string> arr = value.Split(',').ToList();
```

Comment: +1 showing the version with Select, even if it's not needed.  It lets the OP compare to see what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the Select:

```
value = "one,two,three,four";

List<string> arr = value.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = "one,two,three,four";
List<string> arr = value.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use LINQ here, instead you can simply do this:

```cs
string value = "one,two,three,four";
List<string> arr = value.Split(',').ToList();
```